# How do you expand a tree while traversing it?

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search

I'm making a program to solve a 3-puzzle(with 3 blocks and a blank) , which is a smaller version of an 8-puzzle. I'm attempting to construct a tree by shifting the blocks adjacent to the black into the blank space; thus every state can give 2 states(branching factor = 2). I'm using breadth-first search to solve the tree, but to traverse the tree, it first has to be made(expanded). Since i just can't continue expanding the tree forever i have to have some means of expanding the tree to a certain depth and then traversing it. So when the traversal reaches the last level, the expand() function would be called to expand it further.Can someone give me a clear method or algorithm to carry this idea out? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: @ tucuxi no, i said that it's a 3 puzzle, due to which the space can only be along a side(because there are only 4 squares). Therefore there can only be 2 blocks adjacent to the space.

Comment: (deleted my previous comment - you're right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `set` of all the different board-states. Two board-states are different if they have a different piece (blank counts as a piece) in any of the positions. You can build a string to describe a state by concatenating all the digits using a consistent order; most languages/libraries support sets of strings directly.

You should only expand() non-visited board-states. Whenever you visit a state for the first time, you should add it to the "visited states" `set`. Before expanding any state, check to see if it is there already.

The full algorithm (for general breadth-first, no-duplicate search) is:

```
place initial state into "pending" (a queue)
place initial state into "visited" (a set)
while "pending" is not empty,
   extract its first state, called "next"
   if it is not present in "visited",
      if it is the goal, report success, ending the algorithm
      otherwise, add all its children at the end of "pending"    
if you reach this point, there is no way to reach a goal state from a start state
```

Comment: How would i expand the tree? When a state has no children in the tree, should i simply pass the current state `t` to the expand(state t) function to create 2 new children for that node? or would it be a better idea to expand all the nodes at the last level at once?

Comment: Provide a "parent" field to each of your states (not used in comparisons of state equality). Whenever you add a child state to the queue, specify your current state as its parent. You will be building the tree as you explore it, just as you wanted. To find the optimal path to the goal, just follow the chain of parents from the goal state (until you reach the starting node, which has no parent).